# MySQL deadlocks with composite primary key and trigger autoincrement

Tags: mysql, triggers, deadlock, auto-increment, composite-primary-key

I have standalone server and 2000 users online (not so many).
MySQL DB 5.6 with table request_action (composite PK without autoincrement BUT increment is in trigger, you can see it below):

```
  CREATE TABLE `request_action` (
  `ra_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `cl_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ra_r_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `ra_tr_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `ra_ss_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ra_h_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ra_uch_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `ra_u_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `ra_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ra_uct_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ra_text` longtext NOT NULL,
  `ra_datetime_reply` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ra_reply` longtext NOT NULL,
  `ra_line_breaks` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ra_plan` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ra_shw` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `ra_to_u_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `ra_created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ra_seen` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ra_seen_u_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`cl_id`,`ra_id`),
  KEY `rm_r_id` (`ra_r_id`),
  KEY `ra_u_id` (`ra_u_id`),
  KEY `ra_plan` (`ra_plan`),
  KEY `ra_rat_id` (`ra_ss_id`),
  KEY `ra_h_id` (`ra_h_id`),
  KEY `ra_tr_id` (`ra_tr_id`),
  KEY `ra_id` (`ra_id`),
  KEY `ra_datetime` (`ra_datetime`,`ra_seen`),
  KEY `ra_shw` (`ra_shw`,`ra_seen`,`ra_to_u_id`),
  KEY `ra_r_id` (`ra_r_id`,`ra_tr_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Trigger on this table (BEFORE INSERT):

```
if (cast(NEW.ra_id as UNSIGNED) = 0) then
SET NEW.ra_id = (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(ra_id)+1, 1) FROM request_action WHERE cl_id = NEW.cl_id);
end if
```

AND I have deadlocks many times in a day (( For example, 100 in a day.

```
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2019-02-21 21:09:34 7f5e11f3b700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 2947112777, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 11, locked 11
LOCK WAIT 5 lock struct(s), heap size 1184, 3 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 19952598, OS thread handle 0x7f5e10e38700, query id 248552715 192.168.0.7 vh_uon_com_ru
insert into request_action (
                    ra_r_id,
                    ra_u_id,
                    ra_datetime,
                    ra_text,
                    ra_datetime_reply,
                    ra_reply,
                    ra_plan,
                    cl_id,
                    ra_tr_id,
                    ra_ss_id,
                    ra_h_id,
                    ra_uch_id,
                    ra_to_u_id,
                    ra_uct_id,
                    ra_shw
                ) values (
                    40053,
                    906,
                    '2019-02-21 21:09:34',
                    'Звонок',
                    '2019-02-21 21:09:34',
                    '',
                    '0',
                    698,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    171114,
                    0,

*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 2320 page no 546708 n bits 104 index `PRIMARY` of table `request_action` trx id 2947112777 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 2947112774, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 11, locked 11
5 lock struct(s), heap size 1184, 3 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 19952597, OS thread handle 0x7f5e11f3b700, query id 248552705 192.168.0.7
insert into request_action (
                    ra_r_id,
                    ra_u_id,
                    ra_datetime,
                    ra_text,
                    ra_datetime_reply,
                    ra_reply,
                    ra_plan,
                    cl_id,
                    ra_tr_id,
                    ra_ss_id,
                    ra_h_id,
                    ra_uch_id,
                    ra_to_u_id,
                    ra_uct_id,
                    ra_shw
                ) values (
                    25182,
                    906,
                    '2019-02-21 21:09:34',
                    'Звонок',
                    '2019-02-21 21:09:34',
                    '',
                    '0',
                    698,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    171113,
                    0,

*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 2320 page no 546708 n bits 104 index `PRIMARY` of table `request_action` trx id 2947112774 lock mode S locks gap before rec
*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 2320 page no 546708 n bits 104 index `PRIMARY` of table `request_action` trx id 2947112774 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
```

In my.cf we have the following options:

```
max_connections = 10000
key_buffer_size = 1024M
join_buffer_size = 256M
read_buffer_size = 256M
sort_buffer_size = 256M
tmp_table_size = 512M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M
max_heap_table_size = 512M

thread_cache_size = 8192
query_cache_type = 1

query_cache_size = 15G
wait_timeout = 6000
connect_timeout = 15
interactive_timeout = 60
max_allowed_packet = 512M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 64M

innodb_log_file_size                    = 512M
innodb_log_buffer_size                  = 2G
innodb_buffer_pool_size                 = 20G
```

Could you please help me with deadlock issue? How can I fix it? Should I rerun queries in deadlocks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR -- You can't do concurrent inserts while you're trying to generate a new incrementing id per distinct `cl_id`. You must use a table-lock to do that, causing concurrent inserts to run serially.

---

The reason `AUTO_INCREMENT` gets around this deadlock is that it acquires a brief table lock to generate the next id. Technically, this causes all concurrent sessions doing INSERT to execute serially. Fortunately, the table-lock is very brief. By default, it's released as soon as the id is generated. You can read more here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html

Whereas your method of generating id's is causing deadlocks because it's using *two* locking operations:

1. One X-lock for creating the row.
2. One S-lock for reading the table. When you read a table as part of an INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE, you create a shared lock on the rows you read.

But the locks are not acquired together, there's a brief time between the two steps, and that's where the race condition occurs. We can demonstrate this by using two tables:

```
mysql> create table foo ( id serial primary key);
mysql> insert into foo (id) values (1);

mysql> create table bar ( id serial primary key);

mysql> create trigger b before insert on bar 
       for each row set new.id=(select max(id) from foo);
```

Now we have a trigger on `bar` that will read some row in `foo` to get the max(id).

```
mysql> begin;
mysql> insert into bar () values ();
```

That should create a new row in `bar` using the value it read from `foo`. But the transaction is still open.

In a second window, do this:

```
mysql> update foo set id = 2;
...
```

This hangs, waiting for its X-lock on `foo`. It can't update `foo`, because there's already an S-lock on it, placed by the session in the first window.

Go back to the first window and run:

```
mysql> update foo set id = 3;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

This creates a circular lock-wait, which is what a deadlock is. Both transactions are waiting for locks held by the other transaction. We see in the second window, that transaction was killed:

```
mysql> update foo set id = 2;
...
ERROR 1213 (40001): Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

---

**"How can I fix it? Should I rerun queries in deadlocks?"**

One workaround is to force the concurrent sessions to run serially, by acquiring a table lock on all the tables referenced by your INSERT or the trigger before you attempt to insert.

```
mysql> begin;
mysql> lock tables foo write, bar write;
mysql> insert into bar () values ();
```

The second window hangs, but it's hanging on a table-lock, not a row-lock this time.

```
mysql> update foo set id = 2;
...
```

In the first window, finish the transaction. Unlocking the table-locks implicitly commits the transaction.

```
mysql> unlock tables;
```

The second window stops waiting, and successfully completes its update.

```
mysql> update foo set id = 2;
...
Query OK, 1 row affected (3.50 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

Note it had been waiting for 3.5 seconds which is how long it took me to go back to the first window and commit the transaction.

Making the sessions insert serially limits the throughput of your app, because sessions are queuing up. But it avoids deadlocks.

Comment: May I add “lock tables” into my trigger? Or only before insert query in my code?!

Comment: You should do it before the insert query in your code. I think it would be too late to avoid the race condition if you do it in the trigger.

Comment: What about this construction in trigger - "select max() .. for update" and release lock after this?

Comment: I don't think you can do that either. Releasing locks implicitly commits the transaction, but you cannot start or commit a transaction from a trigger.

Comment: If you're doing 5 inserts in the same script, they should have worked. Once you lock tables in one session, you can write to the table in the same session without trouble. It's _other_ sessions that have to wait until your session releases its locks.

Comment: It's working, thanks for helping. But at the moment I have message "mysql 10s waited locks ratio, mysql_local.table_locks (locks), mysql 10s waited locks ratio = 52%" ... I think it's not a problem to solve, yes?

Comment: As I described, using table locks is likely to cause concurrent sessions to wait for each other in a queue for access to the table. You should minimize the length of transactions and release locks as promptly as you can. Optimize queries to make them as quick as possible, and don't run other unnecessary code before you commit the transaction. Other than that, if the throughput is satisfactory, it's okay.